# Scroll to bottom of a list edit form dialog box in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, edit-form

I have a SharePoint list. And there are 2 views in this list named 'View 1' and 'View 2'. I've set 'Launch forms in a dialog' option to 'Yes' in list settings.

I'm editing the list by clicking on '**edit** this list'. See below screenshot:

[image]

Now when I click on 'Item 1' as shown in above picture, the below dialog box opens:

[image]

What I want is to **go to bottom** of this **dialog box** on click of 'Item 1' or 'Items 2' and so on and **only for 'View 1'** and not for 'View 2'.

I tried adding below script on the edit form but it didn't work:

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    var $contents = $("iframe").contents();
    $contents.scrollTop($contents.height());
});
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this serves your need.
[image]

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var scrolled = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        scrolled = scrolled + 400;

        jQuery(".ms-core-overlay").animate({
            scrollTop: scrolled
        });
    });
</script>
```

I did this work around from this link..
http://jsfiddle.net/xEFq5/10/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works, but it is scrolling to bottom for both the views. Any idea how to restrict it for only one view ?

Comment: can you explain how you are creating views? out of box views or designer views?

Comment: Both are out of the box views.

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer. The code wasn't displayed properly in the comment section so I added it as an answer. Thanks :)


Thanks :)

Comment: it's  great ......  :)

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this sharepoint UI dialog using javascript code by giving particular Url in place of **options.url**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        OpenAssetPortalBrowserDialog();

    });

    function OpenAssetPortalBrowserDialog() {

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl);
            Web = clientContext.get_web();
            clientContext.load(Web);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                options.url = "Give your URL Here";
                options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(this, CloseAssetPortalBrowserCallback);
                SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
            }, function() {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            });

            function CloseAssetPortalBrowserCallback(result, target) {
                // to do on popup close

            }
</script>
```

Comment: Where should I put this code ? Also I don't see any code to go to bottom of the page. @Pradeep Kumar

Comment: create a custom editform.aspx for your view from designer and give your page url in options.url-section

Comment: this code is only to show custom dialog not for to go to the bottom of page..

Comment: This doesn't serve my purpose, it'll just open a dialog box on page load. I think I didn't convey my purpose well. I've now edited the question with screenshots explaining my requirement in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the complete answer:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var scrolled = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var editItemURL = window.location.href;
        var viewURL1= "URL of the view for which you want to scroll to bottom";
        if(editItemURL.indexOf(viewURL1) !== -1)
        {
            scrolled = scrolled + 2000;
            jQuery(".ms-core-overlay").animate({
                scrollTop: scrolled
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```